# how to select tag with attr() and that attr have space between in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

how to select tag with **attr()** method and that **attr()** have space between string in jquery

for example my attribute is `data-compare` and this attribute have dynamic value from api

some time `data-compare` value have space between that string like : 'test test test'

```
$(`#compare_modal_table td[data-compare=${item}]`)
```

but this is not work because space is exist between string and console log syntax error

how can i get this ?

Comment: Use quotes -- see [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+select+attribute+value+with+spaces) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: _Elements_, not tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make this :

```js
$('#compare_modal_table td[data-compare="' + ${item} + '"]')
```